# How can i override print function in Python 2.2.1 (WebLogic version)

Tags: python, wlst

How to override print function in Python 2.2 in order to being able to redirect output to custom logger.

Comment: There is no `print` function in Python 2.2, only the `print` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a version of 2.2 to check (why are you using such an old version?), but I suspect the following is valid for all 2.x.

---

The `print` statement recognizes a first argument beginning with `>>` to indicate which file to write to.

The following are identical:

```
print "foo", "bar"
print >>sys.stdout, "foo", "bar"
```

As such, you can specify any `file` object as the target file.

```
f = open("log.txt", "w")
print >>f, "foo", "bar"
```

If you want to redirect *every* `print` statement (or at least all the ones that aren't using a specific file as shown above), you can simply replace `sys.stdout` with your desired file.

```
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")
print "foo", "bar"   # Goes to log.txt
```

If you need it, the original standard output is still available via `sys.__stdout__`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems like I could use that! But the goal is not to redirect to a file but to a logger. How can I implement a file like object that can do the trick? By the way, I am using a super old version of python because I am writing scripts which must be executed using wlst (WebLogic Language Scripting Tool)

Comment: Two options are to use the `logging` module instead of `print` statements, or use `subprocess` to open a pipe to an external command that works with the logger. (Assuming either is available in 2.2.)

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to print statement! I can't modify the code. I am calling existing functions which make use of print statements.